# 1064 Error When Converting from SQLite to MySQL in Flask App

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a Flask app, and am converting form SQlite to MySQL, using SQLAlchemy as the ORM the entire time. A query that used to work is now throwing off the below error. Can someone spot the issue with the SQL, so I can trace that back to the SQLAlchemy code?

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 7
[SQL: SELECT user_post.post_id AS user_post_post_id
FROM user_post
WHERE user_post.feed_id IN (SELECT feed.id
FROM feed
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM feed_folder, folder
WHERE feed.id = feed_folder.feed_id AND folder.id = feed_folder.folder_id AND folder.id = %(id_1)s)) AND user_post.user_id IS %(user_id_1)s]
[parameters: {'id_1': 1, 'user_id_1': 1}]
```

which comes from

```
feed_list = db.session.query(Feed.id).filter(Feed.folders.any(id=folder)).subquery()
post_list = db.session.query(UserPost.post_id).filter(UserPost.feed_id.in_(feed_list), UserPost.user_id.is_(user.id)).all()
```

Comment: In MySQL `IS` operator tests the value against boolean literal (i.e. only TRUE, FALSE or UNKNORN allowed, not 1). Replace `user_post.user_id IS %(user_id_1)s` with `user_post.user_id = %(user_id_1)s`.

Comment: That solved it, thank you! I guess that works for SQlite but not MySQL.